# Combining web data and mobile data in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Currently I'm working on a react-native project this includes Web, android and IOS applications.

I'm using Google analytics to create reports from the usage data of all three applications. Now the problem is I didn't found any way to combine web and mobile data to create combined tables in Google analytics. This is necessary because this is a react-native based project.

I'm using Google tag manager to manage the analytics process. We are using Web container for the web module and android and IOS containers for mobile applications. We also use fire-base to capture events from mobile applications. So both android and IOS containers contains fire-base analytics.

So how can I combine data from mobile and web applications to provide combined tables in Google analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know, google analytics already combined all data from mobile and web into single view. If you want to see some difference parts as Page view vs Screen name, you just have to make separate View.